# using cin to read in a random number of lines from the input stream c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm designing an algorithm, where the first number is going to tell me how many lines of codes the file will contain. So, it's like:

```
3      /// number of lines that need to be configured
56227
-19
322
```

```
int main(){
    int variable;

    cin >> variable;

    for (int i = 0; i < variable; i++){
         cin >> variableTwo;

         /// Then algorithm with a bunch of code?
    }
}
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

No it will not because you have an unclosed brace for the for loop structure and you have not declared the type of `variableTwo`. This will work instead....

```
int main(){
    int variable;
    int variableTwo;

    cin >> variable;

    for (int i = 0; i < variable; i++){
         cin >> variableTwo;

         /// Then algorithm with a bunch of code?
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't post a real answer for trivial typos.

Comment: But it's the bug in the code, and he asked if it could work? I said no and why and posted the correct code

Comment: Simple typos should be closed with a comment, they serve no lasting purpose for the site.

Comment: Check my reputation and see if I can comment, it was the only way

Comment: I know you can't comment. That doesn't mean you should post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the second variable can run your code without an error. So declare the `variableTwo`. And if you wanted to store the given lines value that you wanted to configure, for further use then please use an Array variable instead.

For example:

```
int variableTwo;
```

or

```
int variableTwo[size];
for(i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    cin>>variableTwo[i];
    //your rest code
}
```